# When debugging using xcode how do we know fast the frame of a view (or other information)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, uiview

This has bugged me several time.

I am debugging a custom subview for example.

I want to know the type of subviews that my custom subviews have.

I type:

```
(lldb) po self.subviews
error: property 'subviews' not found on object of type 'BGBaseOfAllUIView *'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
(lldb)
```

Which is idiotic given that self is has UIView as ancestor and does support .subviews property.

I type

```
(lldb) po self
(BGDetailBusinessViewController *) $2 = 0x088d01f0 <BGDetailBusinessViewController: 0x88d01f0>
```

Which is not a lot of information. It doesn't explain what the frame is or where things go.

The so called variable view is also not helping.

[image]

Say I want to know some simple information. What is self.subviews? What is self.frame?

Why getting something so simple is so difficult?

The only way how to do so is to borrow a code from my friend and add

```
#define CLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#define PO(x) CLog(@#x ": %@", x)
```

But that's not real time. I have to modify the program first and insert stuff just to get that simple information.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid moaning in your questions - people have to read a lot of "it doesn't work how I want it to" before they can get to any real questions - which is what we are here for not for listening to you vent your frustrations.

First thing to note is: `BGDetailBusinessViewController` is a viewController and not a view - so no it does not have subviews but it manages a view hierarchy. The root view would be the ivar called `view`.

So to get the subviews you would need to do something like

```
po [self.view subviews]
```

Comment: I remove the ooooo. I was sure self is UIView. Let me check again.

Comment: Okay +1 for you for pointing that out. I wouldn't moan here if the issue were that simple. I modified the question to use a sample where self is indeed a uiview.

Comment: interestingly po self.subviews doesn't work but po [self subviews] work.

Comment: Let's wait a while if there is any other answer. You have answered partially and so far is the best answer. Thanks for that.

Comment: I guess it could be that `@property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews;` is declared in a category and not actually on `UIView` and perhaps lldb is a bit stricter than the compiler about what it looks at/recognises